# getline() and ncurses output not ideal

Tags: c++, getline, ncurses

If I have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ncursesw/curses.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    initscr();
    curs_set(0);
    int row, col;
    getmaxyx(stdscr, row, col); //forgot these originally

    string name, server, displayanswer;

        ifstream nameserverinput("nameserver.txt");

        if(!nameserverinput.is_open()){
            erase();
            string error = "nameserver.txt could not be found. Exiting...";
            mvprintw(row/2 - 1, (col-error.size())/2, error.c_str());
            refresh();
            sleep(5);
            return 0;
        }

        nameserverinput >> name >> server >> displayanswer;
        nameserverinput.close();

    erase();
    string error = (name + " (" + server + ") " + "is not in a game.");
    mvprintw(row/2 - 1, (col-error.size())/2, error.c_str());
    refresh();

}
```

My output is completely fine, everything in the center on one line nicely. A sample of nameserver.txt would be:

```
imaqtpie
na
y
```

If I replace nameserverinput >> name with getline(nameserverinput, name) like so:

```
 getline(nameserverinput, name)
 nameserverinput >> server >> displayanswer;
```

Then my output is this:

```
(NA) is not in a game.                   imaqtpie
```

For some reason everything sent past "name" is sent to the start of the line. I guessing maybe that this is getline() shoving something at the end of "name" which ncurses mvprintw output isn't enjoying too much. Other than that I couldn't think what the issue would be, since getline() should be working almost identically to the >> operator. I tried replacing everything with getline() to no avail. I need "name" to incorporate the possibility of spaces so what is my other option? (Trying this without ncurses and instead using cout << x << endl presented everything ideally, so it must be something to do with mixing getline() and ncurses).

Comment: *I guessing maybe that this is getline() shoving an escape character like \n at the end of "name"* - No, it doesn't, and reading some [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) on functions you don't know the behaviour of is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Something is missing from the example (`initscr` is never called).

But assuming that you simply omitted that in cut/paste: `getline` would be echoing to the standard output.  Generally speaking, you cannot mix stdio and ncurses calls (or any *curses* implementation), since ncurses buffers things in its own way before writing to the screen, and the buffer is not necessarily one known to stdio.

If you *must* mix stdio and ncurses, you have to do `fflush`'s to ensure that you've finished writing before switching back to ncurses (and `refresh`'s before going back to stdio).

Using the suggested revisions (plus ensuring that the program exits normally), I see the same behavior with/without getline for this example:

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <ncursesw/curses.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int
main()
{
    initscr();
    curs_set(0);
    int row, col;
    getmaxyx(stdscr, row, col); //forgot these originally

    string name, server, displayanswer, postgameanswer;

    ifstream nameserverinput("nameserver.txt");

    if (!nameserverinput.is_open()) {
        erase();
        string error = "nameserver.txt could not be found. Exiting...";
        mvprintw(row / 2 - 1, (col - error.size()) / 2, error.c_str());
        refresh();
        sleep(5);
        wgetch(stdscr);
        endwin();
        return 0;
    }

#if 1
    getline(nameserverinput, name);
    nameserverinput >> server >> displayanswer >> postgameanswer;
#else
    nameserverinput >> name >> server >> displayanswer;
#endif
    nameserverinput.close();

    erase();
    string error = (name + " (" + server + ") " + "is not in a game.");
    mvprintw(row / 2 - 1, (col - error.size()) / 2, error.c_str());
    refresh();
    wgetch(stdscr);
    endwin();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've editted in initscr() to show how it was originally. I've now (in my own code) placed initsrc() initialisation after nameserverinput.close(), and placed fflush(stdout) and fflush(stderr) (to be safe) before it but I'm still having the issue (I also commented out any use of cout to be safe)

Comment: Just a slightly useless fyi, the "postgame" variable isn't meant to be in my code, forgot to take it out. Copying the code you just re-posted, my output definitely changes depending on whether getline() is used or not. I'm running this on Linux (a Raspberry Pi) if that makes any difference.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to make a difference (I tested on Debian6 with current- and stable ncurses, just in case, but don't have a matching configuration).

Comment: Fair enough, did you happen to get it to work using fflush? If not I might try avoiding stdio like you imply and just write name/server/display values in the source code.

Comment: Actually, once I was able to run the example, I saw nothing going to stdout -- only ncurses output.  Perhaps the problem isn't in ncurses, but in the C++ runtime (which version of g++ are you using?)

Comment: 4.6.3 (came with the Debian distribution).

Comment: hmm - Debian6 has 4.4.5 (with ncurses 5.7) and my Debian8 beta has 4.9.1 (ncurses 5.9+) .  On both, I tested with current ncurses as well. Both are giving me the same results.  (On the newer version, sleep required an include).  At the moment I don't more ideas :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72483/discussion-between-silversonic-and-thomas-dickey).